# Change static field value by maven

Tags: java, maven

I have a class like this:

```
public final class MyClass {

    private static String VERSION = "1.0.0";
}
```

Is there a simple way to change **VERSION** field value and instead of **1.0.0** write 
maven project version value ( **${project.version}** ), e.g. 2.0.0-SNAPSHOT?

P.S. it can be done for example during *generate-sources* phase.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best option for this case is to use the [templating-maven-plugin](http://www.mojohaus.org/templating-maven-plugin/) which solves this completely.

So this means simply put a class template into `src/main/java-templates` containing the correct package location and put in your placeholders like `${project.version}` etc.
During the build those classes will be correctly filtered and automatically build into the resulting jar ...

```xml
<plugins>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>templating-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>filter-src</id>
        <goals>
          <goal>filter-sources</goal>
        </goals>
            <configuration>              
              <!-- 
                Note the two following parameters are the default one. 
                These are specified here just as a reminder. 
                But as the Maven philosophy is strongly about conventions, 
                it's better to just not specify them.
              -->
              <sourceDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/java-templates</sourceDirectory>
              <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/java-templates</outputDirectory>
            </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
</plugins>
```